# Rewrite rule that checks for file, if not found, try with .php extension, if still not found, further rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

OK I have a directory on a site with a few files let's say:

```
faqs.php
index.php
info.php
```

If people come to my site with a url like:

```
site.com/faqs
```

I want them to get faqs.php so I do one of these:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

I also want any file that still is not found after checking for the .php extension, to show:

```
faqs.php?question=PATH
```

So if they show up with a:

```
site.com/what_is_your_problem_anyways
```

They will get:

```
faqs.php?question=what_is_your_problem_anyways
```

What is the smartest way to do this without making index, info and faqs redirect?

Comment: I assume you mean `faqs.php`, not `faqs.com`? Well, you could simply check if the REQUEST_FILENAME plus appended `.php` still doesn’t refer an existing file maybe …

Comment: Oh yeah, fixed that. How would I check that though?

Comment: Similar to how you checked if the filename without extension was an existing file or not …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To internally add .php ext if .hp file is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# if not found then redirect to /faqs.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /faqs.php?question=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should allow you to achieve what you want

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /faqs.php?question=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` once you know the redirects works.